# KornShell - grouping conditions in an IF statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, conditional-statements, ksh

I got the following snippet failing on KornShell (ksh):

```
var1="1"
var2="2"
if [ ( "$var1" != "" -o "$var2" != "") -a ( "$var1" = "$var2" -o " "$var1" = "x") ]; then
   echo "True"
else
   echo "False"
fi
```

> ksh: syntax error: `"$var1"' unexpected

As I understand, this fails because the parentheses run in a subshell where var1 is not recognized.
So how could sets of conditions be grouped inside the square brackets?

N.B. I already know the following solutions and do not want to use them:

- Put the conditions in separate nested if statements.
- Optimize/rearrange conditions in order to put them in only one set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ -n $1 || -n $2 ]] && [[ $1 == "$2" || $1 == x ]]; then
        echo "True"
else
        echo "False"
fi
```

Run:

```
$ ./if.sh "" ""
False

$ ./if.sh 1 2
False

$ ./if.sh 1 1
True

$ ./if.sh x 2
True
```

If you are wondering why your code fails:

1. You need to escape the parentheses `\(`
2. There have to be a spaces around the parantheses
3. And you have a typo, there is a superfluous `"` floating around

So this ...

```
if [ ( "$var1" != "" -o "$var2" != "") -a ( "$var1" = "$var2" -o " "$var1" = "x") ]; then
                                                         typo ---^              ^
                                     ^------------------ missing spaces --------^
```

... should look like this ...

```
if [ \( "$var1" != "" -o "$var2" != "" \) -a \( "$var1" = "$var2" -o "$var1" = "x" \) ]; then
```

and then it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Adrian, it's much appreciated.
Escaping the parentheses did not work I still got "ksh: [: missing ]" as error. I used the first proposition: breaking down the square brackets into two ANDed sets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double square brackets.. [[--------]]

Hope it helps.

Regards.